# Django-MongoDB-Engine: Support for $addToSet, $push, $pull, etc?

Tags: django, mongodb

I'm using the django-mongodb-engine, django-nonrel, djangotoolbox projects / packages to get django talking with mongodb. Is there any way through the normal django ORM and QuerySets to take advantage of the update modifiers supplied by mongodb such as $addToSet, $pop, $push, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop into the lower level api and do [raw_updates](http://django-mongodb.org/reference/lowerlevel.html#django_mongodb_engine.contrib.MongoDBManager.raw_update)